# Format JS result into Currency Format

Tags: javascript, php, html, format, currency

I want to convert the format of the result into currency.
JS

```
$(function(){
    function credit (selector) {
         $(selector).each(function () {
             var total = 0,
             column = $(this).siblings(selector).andSelf().index(this);
             $(this).parents().prevUntil(':has(' + selector + ')').each(function () {
                 total += parseFloat($('td.credit:eq(' + column + ')', this).html()) || 0;
             })
             $(this).html(total);
         });
    }
    credit('td.creditsubtotal');
    credit('td.credittotal');
    });
```

The result is show in a class tag. I want it to be shown in a currency format. Eg. $ x,xxx.xx ($ 1,234.56)

http://jsfiddle.net/2c6p928x/

Comment: without the values its hard to suggest things, can you add this to a jsfiddle or post your html with the values? what is your output currently?

Comment: attached the jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$(function(){
function credit (selector) {
     $(selector).each(function () {
         var total = 0,
         formattedTotal, numCredit, strCredit 
         column = $(this).siblings(selector).andSelf().index(this);
         $(this).parents().prevUntil(':has(' + selector + ')').each(function () {
              strCredit = $('td.credit:eq(' + column + ')', this).html() || "";
              console.log(strCredit);
              numCredit = Number(strCredit.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
              console.log(numCredit);
              total += parseFloat(numCredit) || 0;
         })
         formattedTotal = total.toFixed(2).replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$&,');
         $(this).html('$'+formattedTotal);
     });
}
credit('td.creditsubtotal');
credit('td.credittotal');
```

});

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chridam/qmws39eq/)**

Comment: Your code works perfect. Just one more thing? This code works only when the <td> tags have numbers. How do i get it to work if it has a prefix like "$" . The sum function doesnt work when i have a prefix. How do i get that working.

Comment: How do I ignore the characters and take only the numbers in the <td> tag?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include the part which strips the non-numeric characters in a string.

Comment: Did you test the code with numbers more than $1,000,000.00 ?

Comment: Works Smooth. Thanks you so much!!

Comment: @AhamedZulfan No worries, glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) library.

This is an example, how to format the `total` variable in currency format:

```
$(this).html(numeral(total).format('$0,0.00'));
```

It is only 3k, but supports multiple different formats and has localizations.